# What output does the getBBox() give?

Tags: javascript, svg

I have applied the getBBox() function on my svg and it gives me x coord, y coord, width and height. I don't really understand what these values exactly represent as I was expecting four sets of x,y coords but got just one. can anybody explain to me what this output actually represents?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is the getBBox() SVGRect calculated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179173/how-is-the-getbbox-svgrect-calculated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It returns the bounding box of the element. The X and Y values are the coordinates of the top left corner of the element. You can add width and height to the x and y to get the coordinates of the other corners